# Getting virtual machine's virtual disk usage in vmware with pyvmomi

Tags: pyvmomi

I've recently started using pyvmomi to get a detailed inventory of vmware servers.I want to get the virtual disk usage of the virtual machine.

I can find the capacity(total amount) of each virtual disk in vim.vm.device.VirtualDisk, and i can find disk usage of VM in vim.VirtualMachine.storage.How can I get the usage of each vitrual disk?

For example, the vm disk has two vitrual disks.
vm disk summary :10GB  usage:8GB
vitrual disk 1 :6GB usage:5GB
vitrual disk 2 :4GB usage:3GB
I want get 5GB and 3GB